# Road map to learning about $\ell$-adic representations of $\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: modular-forms, advice, galois-representations

I am interested in learning about the congruence relations satisfied by the coefficients of modular forms, in particular I am interested in learning more about $\tau(n)$, the coefficients of the weight $12$ modular forms $\Delta=q\prod_{n\ge 1}(1-q^n)^{24}$. I am aware that it satisfies some [remarkable congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function#Congruences_for_the_tau_function). Recently I got to know that these mysterious congruences were explained by Swinnerton-Dyer in light of the existence of the following representation(which was conjectured by Serre and proved by Deligne):
\begin{equation*}
\rho_{\ell}:\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})
\end{equation*}
with $\text{tr}\rho_{\ell}(\text{Frob}_p)=\tau(p)$ and $\det \rho_{\ell}(\text{Frob}_p)=p^{11}$ for $p\ne \ell$.

I want to learn more in this direction and I found the book "Abelian $\ell$-adic representations and Elliptic Curves" by Serre. But this is not an easy book to read and seems to require some non-trivial pre-requisite(such as algebraic groups), which is currently beyond me.

**My background**: I am familiar with basic representation theory but have never studied Galois representations specifically. I am familiar with basic undergraduate algebra(including finite Galois theory). I also know basic commutative algebra and algebraic number theory. I am also familiar with the basic theory of compact Riemann surfaces. I am currently learning some geometry from Vakil's FOAG.

What would be a reasonable road map from my current state to understanding "these things"? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, Swinnerton-Dyer's paper is actually very readable! There are also a sequence of classical papers by Ribet on images of Galois representations, which are highly relevant. A beginner reference is the last chapter of Diamond and Shurman. But, given that you have a decent background, I highly recommend the [notes and video lectures](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/MSRI/) from a recent course given by Kevin Buzzard at MSRI. It would be a good idea to blackbox the construction of Galois representations from modular forms (except perhaps in weight 2), and focus on their properties.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhsb6tmzSpiysoRR0bZozub-MM0k3mdFR) to the video lectures. They start from infinite Galois theory, and go on from there.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the resources you shared. Is the relevant paper by Swinnerton-Dyer named "On $\ell$-adic representations for coefficients of modular forms"?